# Passing shell command to a terminal application from an App in Mac

Tags: python, macos, argument-passing, exit-code, py2app

I have frozen a python based GUI script using Py2app successfully but I run into trouble using this app on Mac. This app is supposed to send arguments/parameters to Clustal, a terminal-based application, but it instead returns an error **non-zero exit status 127, '/bin/sh: clustal: command not found'**.

I found that my frozen app can send shell command successfully when I execute the same app from *Frozen_apl.app>Contents>MacOS>Frozen_apl* (which is a UNIX executable file).

Why do these shell commands get blocked when they are passed directly from app? How can I get around this problem?

Note: Clustal is properly installed and its path is properly set. I use OS X 10.9. I have same script frozen for Ubuntu and Windows and they work just fine.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with the arguments, but with finding `clustal` itself. You said it's properly installed and the path set, but where is it, and how are you setting PATH? (Note that each process has its own PATH, and just because you set it in interactive shells doesn't mean it's getting set for shells spawned by your app.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thanks for your comment!. Clustal is installed in /usr/local/bin/ and path is set in .bash_profile, if that's what you are asking. Can you think of any reason why it works when running UNIX executable file within app directory but not when running the app itself?

Comment: Strange; /usr/local/bin is actually in the default PATH in OS X. I'm not sure exactly how Py2app spawns things, but I suppose it's possible it sets a different (minimal) PATH, then runs a shell in a mode that doesn't init with .bash_profile. I'd try using a full path for `clustal`, and see if that fixes it. If it does, there's probably a better option but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Turns out frozen app works properly if I call `clustal` using complete path. I will have to change my script to obtain full path of `clustal` and then exceute it. Thanks for the suggestion! You could post this as an answer for me to accept or else, I will post sometime in the future on description of how I got around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Py2app 0.6.4 minor feature release:

> Issue #15: py2app now has an option to emulate the shell environment you get by opening a window in the Terminal.
>
> Usage: `python setup.py py2app --emulate-shell-environment`
>
> This option is experimental, it is far from certain that the implementation works on all systems.

Using this option with Py2app solved the problem of blocked communication between Py2app-frozen app and Os X shell.

Comment: Recently found that this is not a complete solution. It certainly works in the Mac in which the app is frozen but when I use this frozen app on a different Mac, it fails to establish proper connection to the shell. However, everything works just fine if I open this frozen app through the terminal instead of double clicking the app.

Answer (score 1):

[Based on the discussion in comments] This isn't a problem with the arguments, it's due to the spawned shell not being able to find the `clustal` executable. I'm not sure why this is, since it's in /usr/local/bin/clustal, and since /usr/local/bin is in OS X's default PATH (it's listed in /etc/paths). Using the full path to the executable worked, so it appears the frozen app is spawning a shell with a non-default PATH.

Including the full path (/usr/local/bin/clustal) in the frozen app isn't really an optimal solution; it'd be better to figure out how to get a normal PATH in the spawned shell. But I'm now familiar enough with Py2app to know how to do this. (JeeYem: please give the workaround you came up with in a comment or another answer.)

Comment: after hours of searching, I found a neat option in Py2app itself that does exactly what I was looking for!